# Is the word "sightseeing" tautological?

Tags: meaning, etymology, redundancy, word-formation

Is this word sometimes perceived as "silly" by a native speaker? By "silly" I mean something in itself a bit absurd, because repetitive, naively constructed, given that this word is composed of the noun "sight" (view, what is seen, and also the faculty of seeing) based on the very verb "to see", and the verb "to see" itself.

(If a such word would be created like that in French it would be something like "voirvision"-- in Italian something like "vistavedere", and in my native Romanian "a vedea vedere" or simply "vedere-vedere".)

I am not a native speaker myself and although I knew the correct spelling I think I always "thought" of it as "site-seeing", the seeing of a ... site! (place, location)... Until now.

Looking at its etymology, "sight" is construed [from Old English](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sight#English), and not directly from the modern verb "to see". Isn't the idea of seeing present in the word "sight" so that "sightseeing" sounds tautological and a bit nonsensical, as if seeing double?

Comment: In any language, words that enter common use become accepted. If people had thought they were absurd they would never have become so common. This is just psychology. A different sort of example illustrates this. In Scotland the surname Smellie is not uncommon. It is pronounced “smelly”, although some change its pronunciation to “smiley” and its spelling to Smillie”. When I came to work in Scotland and found my boss’s surname was “Smellie” (pronounced “smelly”) it seemed “silly” at first — but only for about a day. Likewise an English speaker in Germany — Fuchs, Fahrt usw.

Comment: One can see many things, only a few are actually “sights” - features of a place that are worth seeing.

Comment: And my Latin master in the 50s couldn’t abide “television”. (I can’t either, but the content not the hybrid Greco-Latin origin.)

Comment: @k1eran - I guess that answers it: the word is not  perceived as silly, no matter the etymology, given that "sight' clearly and straightforwardly means "worth seeing", and thus "sightseeing" means "seeing what is worth to be seen".

Comment: @David - So, in the end it proves that "sightseeing" is not silly at all, but it seems that even if it were it wouldn't be so in English! :)

Comment: This is not opinion based; there is an undisputed consensus in the existing  answer and in   the comments showing that the possible "silliness" is not "present". I'm voting for  reopening.

Comment: To summarize briefly, in each and every example, the end result is exactly the same: one of the free gifts English gives us is the ability to write redundant repetitions, in spite of the fact that sentences could be shorter in length when simplified, and still mean one and the same.

Comment: The formation might look tautological but its meaning and usage don't allow it.  Established words can not be tautological. Tautology is normally observed in phrases and sentences. For example: "It was adequate enough". Here is another possible tautology using the first sense of "sight" and "seeing": "I'm seeing my sight." The word could possibly be formed as "attractionseeing" too; however, _attraction_ for the tourist attraction sense came much later.

Comment: To see the sights became sightsee.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Sightseeing" is a frequently used word, and not considered "silly".

While one definition of 'sight' is "range of view" (meaning everything you see is in your sight), it also means ["places of interest"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sight), and so isn't tautological.

Comment: interestingly, it seems that the meaning "places of interest" is associated only with the plural

Comment: @cipricus The interest lies in the fact that sightseeing is comprised of two nouns, the first acting attributively. In such compounds, the first noun is only very rarely inflected as it is seen as acting adjectivally and adjectives do not inflect..

Answer (score 1):

Only on second thought, when looking at the base words etymologically can a notion of incongruity be felt, and then it is soon reckoned with as founded on false premises, premises of that sort that the intricacies of language occasionally introduce spuriously into our thinking. The user of English acknowleges instantly that out of the two very different meanings that "sight" has in "eyesight" and "sightseeing", the proper one is "places of interest"; this results from the clue "seeing" and possibly other clues in the context.

Although people do make the mistake of spelling this word "site seeing" there is no contesting of the legitimity of the word "sight" in that compound word. ([Site Seeing or Sightseeing – Which is Correct?](https://writingexplained.org/site-seeing-or-sightseeing))

Interestingly enough, there are very similar constructions in French that would never suggest any idea of silliness. For those  familiar with  this  language the following sentence will show  what I mean.

- *Une  prise de  vue vue sous cet angle produit un reflet*.

The first "vue"  is not  "sight" but "photograph" and    the second is neither, but has to do with seeing again as it is  the  past participle of "voir" (to see).